# Drupal 6 db insert: Strings are getting escaped

Tags: mysql, drupal

Getting driven crazy by this one...

I'm trying to insert a number of rows into a D6 database with a single db_query call.  I've collected the rows as a set of strings, and have then collected them into one big string, something like so:

```
$theData = "(1, 2, 'a'), (3, 4, 'b'), (5, 6, 'c')";
db_query("insert into {table} (int1, int2, str) values %s", $theData);
```

($theData isn't typed like that in my code; it's the result of the code I've written -- a big string containing sets of values wrapped up in parens.)

When this runs, I get an error like:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into 
table (int1, int2, str) values (1,2,\'a\' at line 1 query: insert into 
table (int1, int2, str) values (1,2,\'a\'),(3,4,\'n\'),(5,6,\'c\')...
```

So, db_query or somebody else is escaping the strings before passing the values of to mysql.  How do I keep this from happening?  I could do individual queries for each set of data, but that's wrong/expensive for all the obvious reasons.  Thanks!

Comment: New discovery: I can do this -- db_query("insert into {table} (int1, int2, str) values " . $theData) -- but it feels a little tacky.  Anything better out there?

Comment: Both ways are wrong and insecure, use what Nikit suggested. Drupal 7 has support for inserting multiple rows in a single query, see http://drupal.org/node/310079

Answer (score 1):

```
$theDatas = array("(1, 2, 'a')", "(3, 4, 'b')", "(5, 6, 'c')");

foreach($theDatas as $data) {
  db_query("insert into {table} (int1, int2, str) values %s", $data);
}
```

But it's not recommend to do that, instead of this you should:

```
$theDatas = array(array(1, 2, 'a'), array(3, 4, 'b'), array(5, 6, 'c'));

foreach($theDatas as $data) {
  db_query("insert into {table} (int1, int2, str) values (%d, %d, '%s')", $data[0], $data[1], $data[2]);
}
```

Or you can serialize($theData) and put it "text" format field as one value, then use unserialize() for restoring array - this way is recommend if you want only store data (no searching, indexing etc).

Comment: This is where I was before I started trying to compress all the work into a single call to db_query.  So, there's really no way to do this in D6, short of the hack I came up with?  (@Berdir -- true enough about D7, but this project is pretty far down the road to be thinking about a port.)